# Angulartics not tracking at all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, angulartics

I'm using angulartics for my application to track virtual page views on Google Analytics. This should be enabled by default but no visit to the page is tracked at all.

I should say that I wrapped the Google Analytics js code in a angular directive to be able to turn analytics off on my test server.

Otherwise its pretty standard, I included the angulartics source files in my index.html, added the module to my app.js and removed the ga('send', 'pageview') from the Google Code (as it is described in the docs).

I also found this hard to test. Should I see REST calls in the network console to verify its working? Because I'm not seing any (except the analytics code being loaded from the Google server).

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Flosky

[edit]I should probably also mention that I'm using the angular ui router and not the default one[/edit]

Comment: Try using the google analyics debugger: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna

Comment: Thanks, that helped finding the problem. I got an error: "Storage not available. Aborting hit." That is probaly caused by the fact that I hard coded the domain name and did not use 'auto', like you would normally do: "ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');". I'll try to also set the cookie domain and then it will work hopefully